# Need regex help to modify an XML file

Tags: xml, regex, bbedit

I'm trying to modify an XML file which contains elements holding opening times for branches of a business.  The XML file is inconsistent because for some branches it has just an opening time and a closing time, others have an opening time, a closing time for lunch, a post-lunch opening time and a closing time.

Examples of both types below:

```
<monday>10.00,17.00</monday>
<monday>09.00,12.30,13.30,17.00</monday>
```

I want to reformat these strings to a better format such as the ones below:

```
<monday>
  <open>10.00</open>
  <lunch></lunch>
  <close>17.00</close>
</monday>

<monday>
  <open>09.00</open>
  <lunch>12.30 - 13.30</lunch>
  <close>17.00</close>
</monday>
```

I've been trying to use BBEdit regular expressions on my Mac to make the changes but I'm having difficulty, specifically I think because I'm not sure how I can get the regular expression to replace a subset of the text I tell it to match on.  For example, in pseudo code I want the regular expression to do this:

replace `<monday>time1,time2</monday>`
with `<monday><open>time1</open><lunch></lunch><close>time2</close></monday>`

replace `<monday>time1,time2,time3,time4</monday>`
with `<monday><open>time1</open><lunch>time2 - time3</lunch><close>time4</close></monday>`

I'm not too familiar with regular expressions so I'm making some errors I'm sure but so far I've been trying the below:

replace `>#+\.#+,#+\.#+<`
with `><open>#+\.#+<open><lunch></lunch><close>#+.\#+<`

I understand this isn't going to work anyway because I'm telling the regex to replace the numbers it matches with `#+` with the strings '#+' etc.

How can I achieve what I want to do by regex or other means and also how to I tell the regular expression to use an expression for comparison but only replace a subset of the characters it matches?

Comment: Or ... **just use an XML library** (with support for XPath/XQuery or perhaps just a DOM -- point is **XML is structured and should [always] be treated as such**). No point to make life so complicated and error-prone. Some people may also recommend XSLT, but I have always been in favor of just using a good XML library in most cases. Too many things in XSLT (1.x) are just over-complicated and it involves learning a new (limited) DSL when an XML library can be hosted/used in an already-known general-purpose language.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear, I'm trying to improve the structure of this XML file so I can parse it with predictable results.  There are inconsistencies all through it so I'm just trying to make this XML file fit a consistent structure.

Comment: As long as the file *conforms to XML syntax* (the structure is irrelevant) then an XML library can be used. If the syntax is "questionable" (e.g. unbalanced tags and/or illegal named entities, etc) then it may be possible to use a "fuzzy" XML (but usually HTML) library as an import bridge or there could be a simple "normalization" step. Using regular expressions or manual parsing should really be a last-ditch effort.

Comment: @pst I suppose I should explain the background somewhat.  There is an existing XML file which did not conform to proper XML syntax.  I am using it with an iPhone app.  The XMLParser built into iOS could not parse the existing XML file, so I set about arranging it into a format which could be parsed.  The regex stuff is an intermediary step which will only be done once, thereafter the XMLParser in iOS will handle the data extraction by itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I figured it out quicker than I expected.  Here are the expressions I used:

I used the following find string:

```
(<[a-z]+day>)([0-9]+\.[0-9]+),([0-9]+\.[0-9]+)(</[a-z]+day>)
```

...and the following replace string:

```
\1<open>\2</open><lunch></lunch><close>\3</close>\4
```

to match the following lines:

```
<monday>10.00,17.00</monday>
```

which resulted in the following output:

```
<monday><open>10.00</open><lunch></lunch><close>17.00</close></monday>
```

Comment: Well, if you asked for advice on how to tighten a screw using a chisel, chances are most people would advise you to use a screwdriver instead. If you came back an hour later and reported success at doing it with a chisel, we would all just sigh and let you get on with it.

Comment: @Michael_Kay If you read the question you'll see I asked if there were some other means of solving the issue so feel free to suggest an alternative to my solution, you might even earn yourself some rep.  Before you do, be aware that I'm not planning on using regex to manipulate the file each time it's read.  Just to create a version which is easier to parse with a library (the iOS XMLParser in this case)